# Spring batch job step up defenition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

Im developing a Spring Batch application, technology which by the way I'm new to.

I have made some tutoriais, and read some docs in order to prepare myself to this development.
Im already "confortable" with some of the most common APIs (ItemRead, ItemProcessor, ItemWriter, Setps, Tasklets, Jobs, Parameters...)

My requirement is simple.

1 - Read some data from CSV file.

2 - Fetch an Entity from database by each line of the CSV file.

3 - Update the state of the Entity.

4 - Export a new CSV file with some generated data from each Entity.

My problem is not how to fetch, how to update or how to export a csv file, but more conceptualy how to setup my JOB.

The way I see it I like to end up with a Job something like

**1 - ItemRead            -> to read the whole csv file.**

**2 - ItemProcessor   -> to update the entity.**

**3 - ItemWriter          -> to persist the entity.**

**4 - ItemWriter          -> to export the new CSV file based on the entity state.**

Does it make sense? There's a better way. Am I missisng some pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

updating line by line might not be best idea. Instead I suggest

Job 1

1. Read entire file
2. Write it to the tmp table

Here write **update query** that join original table and tmp table based on primary key.

After query execution, call second job

Job 2

1. Read records from table
2. Write it to the file

Finally clear tmp table for next Job sequence.

This Ans is based on my thought process. there might be other best approaches as well.

Comment: Im using a chunk based approach, so in reality the writing process is not line by line but chunk by chunk, which is configurable. In my case is set to 1000. I think I really have to do this way (just one step with two ItemWriter) to maintain the writing into db and the writing into csv file in the same transaction bundery.

Comment: I endup implementing a custom CompositeItemWriter. I saw in other thread and I think this is what I need.

Comment: Ok @BrunoMiguel, I think even with chunk also.. to update table you need get the record with Id, set values then merge which you need to do for all records. If file is huge then it will costly. In my approach.. work is divided so in future if you need to modify something while reading file like delimiter you no need touch update query & Job 2. If writing to CSV file also need to change you no need to touch other two concerns, So you have separated each concern. If any bug in future then you can easily check with this approach.